# htaccess redirect /foldername/page_name to /page-name

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an issue:
Recently I replaced my old website (no CMS) with a new website (and WordPress as CMS). But a lot of people still try to access the website by old URL's.
Obviously I want to redirect them to the right page.

For example: the previous URL was: `http://domain.com/foldername/page_name`

On the new website that same page is located at `http://domain.com/page-name`

Note #1: The `underscore` has been replaced with a `dash`

Note #2: Some pages may include more underscores. For example: `http://domain.com/foldername/an_other_page_name`

Note #3: Since I use WordPress as CMS, there is already some code in my .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Since I'm not as good with htaccess as some of you I hope someone has the solution, since I'm losing visitors because they can't find the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Just below `RewriteBase` line you can use this **recursive rule**:

```
RewriteRule "^(foldername)/([^_]*)_+([^_]*_.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [N]
RewriteRule "^(foldername)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$" /$2-$3 [L,R=301]
```